# Not how but why a committed file cannot be ignored easily (Practical Purpose of "Assume Unchanged")?

Tags: git, architecture, software-design

Hi i am interested to know the design behind git such that committed files cannot be ignored directly but have to be assumed unchanged. Why is there a tight coupling between them that requires "assumed unchanged" to solve it.

[image]

Comment: You should be veeery careful when using assume unchanged. Normally you should never use that parameter. You have a high risk of loosing your changes. As you tell Git to ignore those changes it really does, meaning each checkout or rebase or merge or pull or whatever that has changes for that file will just overwrite your local version where normally you would get a warning that you will loose your changes. Better fix your project so that you don't need to modify tracked files by providing ....sample files instead or by looking for additional local files besides the checked-in ones.